# Renaming ToC, Lof, etc in a koma-script variance

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, polyglossia, kaobook

i'm having a quite complex problem. i'm using [kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook) -a class that it is based on `koma-script book` - for creating a multilingual document (greek and english). i have define the following class options:

```
% Declaring language class options
\DeclareOption{greek}{%
  \newcommand{\default@lang}{greek}%
  \newcommand{\other@lang}{english}%
}%
\DeclareOption{english}{%
  \newcommand{\default@lang}{english}%
  \newcommand{\other@lang}{greek}%
}%
```

where my set up regarding the fonts and the encoding is the following

```
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\setromanfont[Scale=1.04]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont[Scale=1]{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=.89]{Liberation Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

% Hack because of bug of polyglossia
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\default@lang}{greek}}%
  {
   \RequirePackage[nonumeralsign]{xgreek}
   \newenvironment{greek}{}{}
   \newenvironment{english}{\setlanguage{english}}{\setlanguage{monogreek}}
%    \newcommand{\xpg@main@language}{monogreek}
  }%
  {
   \RequirePackage{polyglossia}
   \setdefaultlanguage{\default@lang}
   \setotherlanguage{\other@lang}
  }
```

The problem is that when i use the command

```
\renewcaptionname{greek}{\contentsname}{Περιεχόμενα}
```

i am getting an error

> Package scrbase Error: `\contentsname' not defined at language` greek'.

i tried to load `polyglossia` with `\setdefaultlanguage{greek}`. In that case, i get an error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \anw@print already defined.
> Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

i also tried to load the `english` option in the document class, which in turn it loads `polyglossia` with `\setdefaultlanguage{english}` and `\setotherlanguage{greek}`. In that case,  hyphenation brakes, either i use `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

So, my question is how can i rename `toc` without breaking hyphenation for the greek language

Answer (score 1):

the problem solved!

for future reference, the issue was caused by the hack

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\default@lang}{greek}}%
  {
   \RequirePackage[nonumeralsign]{xgreek}
   \newenvironment{greek}{}{}
   \newenvironment{english}{\setlanguage{english}}{\setlanguage{monogreek}}
%    \newcommand{\xpg@main@language}{monogreek}
  }%
  {
   \RequirePackage{polyglossia}
   \setdefaultlanguage{\default@lang}
   \setotherlanguage{\other@lang}
  }
```

i replaced this part with the following

```
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{\default@lang}
\setotherlanguage{\other@lang}

\setmainfont[Scale=1.04]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont[Scale=1]{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=.89]{Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
```

and everything works as it expected